# How to know wheter if a user is the owner of a project / master of the owner group (via API)

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-api

I would like to know if there is any way of knowing given a user whether if they are the owners of the project or the master of the group that owns the project.

At least some kind of direct way.

Comment: I know it can be done with multiple API calls and reading from the responses but there should be an easier way, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the Get Single Project api (https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/api/projects.html#get-single-project), it will return a JSON object of the project, where the project owner is listed.

```
curl -X GET -H "PRIVATE-TOKEN: example" "https://gitlab.com/api/v4/projects/projectID"
```